# ImageButton Not Displaying Image from URL

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm facing an issue with displaying an image from a URL using Xamarin.Forms ImageButton. I've verified that the URL is correct because it works in the WinForms version of my app. However, in Xamarin.Forms, the image is not showing.

XAML Code:

```
<ImageButton Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" WidthRequest="60" HeightRequest="60"/>
```

C# ViewModel Property:

```
private string imageUrl = "https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_light_color_272x92dp.png";

public string ImageUrl
{
    get { return imageUrl; }
    set
    {
        if (imageUrl != value)
        {
            imageUrl = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ImageUrl));
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried the same URL in my WinForms version, and it's working fine. Any suggestions on what might be causing the issue in Xamarin.Forms would be greatly appreciated.

```
                            ImageButton image = new ImageButton();
                            image.Clicked += ImageButton_Clicked;
                            image.BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent;
                            image.Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit;
                            image.WidthRequest = 60;
                            image.HeightRequest = 60;
                            try
                            {
                                image.Source = new UriImageSource
                                {
                                    Uri = new Uri(url),
                                    CachingEnabled = false
                                };
                            }
```

Comment: it works fine if you set a background color - the image is white text on a transparent background, so it will not show on a white or light colored background

Comment: I set a black background for my `BackgroundColor` but the `ImageButton` is fully black (no desired white text).

Comment: if you hardcode the url in the XAML does it work?

Comment: No Xaml was like c#.

Comment: Did you try some other image urls?